# Kohana Get All relations at once

Tags: php, orm, kohana

Is it possible to get all object relations at once?

Currently, I'm showing post comments in a loop in the view (`$this->post->comments->find_all()`) however it does not seem to be the best idea (what about caching then?).

How do you usually solve that?

**Edit**
Here's the situation. I got a post controller when I display latest posts (circa 15000 total, 25 per page).

In Post model I've set up relations: has_many with comments, users, options. In the same model I'm getting all posts with limit and offset (for pagination).

In the view I have a foreach loop and I'm displaying posts list:

```
foreach($posts as $post)
{
    /// here in the view I have another loop for comments and options
}
```

Now the issue is: how to add cache?

Answer (score 1):

That's normal usage as I see it.

If you want to make use of caching then take a look at the [cached()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/database/results#select-cached) function. It doesn't do any caching, but returns an object that can be serialized and then cached. The usage would be:

```
$results = Cache::instance()->get('item');

if ( ! $results)
{
    $results = $this->post->comments->find_all()->cached();

    $six_hours = 21600;

    // Save to the cache
    Cache::instance()->set('item', $results, $six_hours);
}

foreach($results as $comment)
{
    var_dump($comment);
}
```

Just a note, the file cache driver automatically serializes the data and I assume the other drivers do some magic internally to store the cached object.

Comment: My answer works fine. what are you having trouble with specifically?

Comment: I created a class extending Kohana Cache module. Basically works perfectly, however when I call it in view `Cache::process($this->post->comments->find_all()->cached())` cache has been created however I can see that queries are proceed. Have no idea why. Any suggestion?